# seeing weird behavior when trying to set body.margin css

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide header and footer on a page when printed from Chrome on Mac.  The header and footer does not appear by default via Chrome on Windows.  Based on a basic Google, looks like I should set page margin to 0 like this:

```
  @page {
    margin:0;
  }
```

Then configure the margin property in @media print body definition like this:

```
  body {
     margin:20px;
  }
```

I'm experiencing weird behavior though.  Setting the property as above does nothing.  Setting the property like this only changes the top margin:

```
  body {
    margin: 20px auto !important;
  }
```

I also tried setting each margin explicitly in this way like this:

```
  body {
    margin: 20px auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px auto !important;
    margin-left: 20px auto !important;
    margin-right: 20px auto !important;
  }
```

However, using this approach also only changes the top margin.  Am I correct in setting the @page{margin:0} in order to eliminate the header and footer from the printout?  What do I need to do in order to properly set the margins in the body like I'm trying to do in the examples above?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest just removing them from the display view entirely with a simple media query;

```css
/* Where the magic happens */

@media print { 
  #header, #footer { display: none !important; } 
}

#header {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #00f;
  display: block;
}

main {
  background-color: #0f0;
  padding: 5rem;
}

#footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
 <h1>Header (will not be in print version)</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <p>The main body of stuff whatever it might be...</p>
</main>

<div id="footer">
  <strong>Footer (will not be in print version)</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to disable specific items from being printed is to explicitly hide those in the **@media print** css definition.

**Here is the css code to hide navbar, footer-section, background and shadows from being printed:**

```
@media print {
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .footer-section {
    display: none;
  }
  * {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

*The above example also sets text colour to **black** for printing.*